# Showing T is not a linear transform

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that **$T(a_1,a_2)=(a_1 + 1, a_2)$** is not a linear transformation

My approach
**$T((a_1,b_2)+(b_1,b_2)) = (a_1 + b_1 + 2, a_2 + b_2)$**

Setting **$c_1 = a_1+b_1$ & $c_2 = a_2 + b_2$**
We see that we are not in our original form
since
**$T(c_1,c_2) = (c_1 + 2, c_2)$**

Is this correct? Can I show T is not a linear transform this way?

Comment: $T((a_{1},a_{2})+(b_{1},b_{2})) = T((a_{1}+b_{1}, a_{2}+b_{2})) = (a_{1}+b_{1}+1, a_{2}+b_{2}) \neq  (a_{1}+b_{1}+2, a_{2}+b_{2})$

Comment: So is my approach bad?

Comment: Do you understand the problem with what you wrote compared to my above comment?

Comment: You have a typo you say "$T((a_1,b_2)+(b_1,b_2))$" where it appears that you mean "$T((a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2))$."  Furthermore $T((a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2))\ne (a_1+b_1 + 2, a_2+b_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have it not quite right.

Can you see the difference between this:

$T((a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2)) = (a_1 + b_1 + 1, a_2 + b_2)\\
T(a_1,a_2)+T(b_1,b_2) = (a_1 + b_1 + 2, a_2 + b_2)\\
T((a_1,a_2)+(b_1,b_2))\ne T(a_1,a_2)+T(b_1,b_2)$

and what you show?

Comment: I see they are not equal that is what i was trying to show.

Comment: yes, but in your work above you show that $T((a_1,a_2) + (b_1,b_2)) = (a_1+b_1+2, a_2+b_2)$ which is simply not correct.  And, you never say anything about $T(a_1,a_2) + T(b_1,b_2).$  And the key point you are trying to show is that the axiom $T(\mathbf a + \mathbf b) = T(\mathbf a) + T(\mathbf b)$ has been violated.

Answer (score 1):

To show that something does not hold, you can give an *counterexample*. Just calculate $T(0,0)$ and $T(1,1)$.

Comment: I don't think you need to calculate more than $T(0,0)$ since it doesn't map $0$ to $0$.

Comment: Yes, that is right but since the OP is a beginner, I wanted him to follow his own try.

Comment: I think whether your advice is to not use arbitrary values (e.g., $a_{i}$'s) or if it is to calculate $T(0,0)$ and $T(1,1)$ then later use linearity after computing $T(0,0)$ and $T(1,1)$, or something else entirely is not clear as written. I interpreted the answer as simply having an unnecessary calculation beyond just seeing that $T(0,0)\neq 0$.

Comment: I do not get your point. I am just continuing the idea of the OP. Of course there are many other ways to see that $T$ is not linear... I think a proof of $T0=0$ for linear maps might confuse the OP at this moment.